# Converting the Cipher Buffer to nsdata and back to cipherBuffer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rsa, private-key

My problem is `CipherBuffer` which is uint8_t i am not able to convert that to `NSData` and get back the same value.the thing is i need to send the encrypted data to server.

Even i get `NSData` from serverside and i need to convert that to (unit8_t *). Is their a way to do that i am using below method to decrypt

`- (void)decryptWithPrivateKey:(uint8_t *)cipherBuffer plainBuffer:(uint8_t *)decryptedBuffer`

Comment: Above specify method is built in? or related to any custom library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert uint8_t to NSData

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)encrypted length:bufferSize];
```

And to convert NSData to uint8_t you can try below method of NSData

```
- (const void *)bytes;
```